# Maven: how to config the tomcat plugin to deploy on https remote site

Tags: ssl, maven, keystore, truststore

I am trying to deploy my web app remotely using the tomcat plugin from maven (mvn tomcat:deploy).

The Tomcat App Server Manager is at https://MyRemoteTomcatInstance/manager.

Firstly, I added the certificate to my trust store with this command:

```
keytool -v -alias mavensrv -import -file /Users/christianachilli/Desktop/KubePartnersLtd.p12 -keystore /Users/christianachilli/trust.jks
```

The file KubePartnersLtd.p12 is the result of exporting the site certificate with the Browser (I used FF 3.6).

Secondly, I added the

> .mavenrc

file and here comes the pain for me! I am not sure of what should I put in it. At the moment I filled it in with:

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Users/christianachilli/trust.jks \
                     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=123456  \
                     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/Users/christianachilli/.keystore \
                     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType= \
                     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="
```

This gives me an error:

> No subject alternative names present

I tried many other combination using the brute force pattern  but I couldn't succeed. I'd really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction about what should be the parameters in

> MAVEN_OPTS

Thanks and regards, 
C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check which CN is `KubePartnersLtd.p12` for, e.g. `localhost` in the following example:

```
$ openssl verify tomcat-p12.crt 
tomcat-p12.crt: /C=Unknown/ST=Unknown/L=Unknown/O=Unknown/OU=Unknown/CN=localhost
[...]
```

Make sure that such CN matches the DNS name you're using in the tomcat plugin configuration. In case they're not the same, you might consider adding an entry to your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29).

Comment: Thanks. Actually the server certificate ha a wrong CN, in the form 'Word1 Word2'. I need to make a new one.